# Is there a way to make a GUI in Kivy that has 3 text input fields on the left and 1 long text input on the right?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to make a GUI in Kivy that has 3 text input fields on the left and 1 long text input on the right? An image and code is shown below:

[image: GUI Layout]

My Code:

```
<CalcScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "Board Foot Calculator"
                bold: True
                background_normal: 'rosewood.png'
                background_down: 'rosewood.png'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            TextInput:
                input_type: 'number'
                id: length
                hint_text: "Length in Inches"
            TextInput:
                id: mainlist
            TextInput:
                input_type: 'number'
                id: width
                hint_text: "Width in Inches"
            TextInput:
                input_type: 'number'
                id: thickness
                hint_text: "Thickness in Inches"
```

**Edit:**
I tried using the GridLayout cols: 2, but it makes the top really large and the buttons below it small. Plus, it is not in the format I would like. An image is also shown below:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `BoxLayouts` to achieve that:

```
<CalcScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Button:
                text: "Board Foot Calculator"
                bold: True
                background_normal: 'rosewood.png'
                background_down: 'rosewood.png'
        BoxLayout:  # contains two items, the BoxLayout below and the long TextInput
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            BoxLayout:   # contains the three TextInputs on the left
                orientation: 'vertical'
                TextInput:
                    input_type: 'number'
                    id: length
                    hint_text: "Length in Inches"
                TextInput:
                    input_type: 'number'
                    id: width
                    hint_text: "Width in Inches"
                TextInput:
                    input_type: 'number'
                    id: thickness
                    hint_text: "Thickness in Inches"
            TextInput:   # this is the long TextInput on the right
                id: mainlist
```

Comment: It didn't copy paste correctly so I just changed random stuff :\

Comment: It did but [this](https://imgur.com/a/ONzuAh4) happened, the top is too large. My code looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/8x0t26Sj) now.

Comment: You can just add something like `size_hint_y: 0.2` to the large `Button`.